# How can we convert .wav file to text by using pocketsphinx?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I installed pocketsphinx in my Linux machine correctly, and now I want to convert an audio file (.wave) to text by using pocketsphinx,how can i do that? is there any clear command and short command to do that? somthing like this command:

```
  ./src/programs/pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 8000 -nfft 2048 -adcdev hw:1,0 -lm 2530.lm -dict 2530.dic myvoice.wav
```

and also how can I do that with using python?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find my answer, pocketsphinx with version 0.8 has an option that can do that:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile myfile.wav
```

however file must be in a specific format: 16khz 16bit mono wav file

Comment: ERROR: "acmod.c", line 80: Acoustic model definition is not specified either with -mdef option or with -hmm ... it suddenly became a whole lot more complex...

Comment: Anyone experiencing the same issue as Mike on an Ubuntu based machine should try installing pocketsphinx-en-us package with apt install.

Comment: You can convert an mp3 to the correct wave format using: ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 myfile.wav